# How to access by 'region' from a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

I am new to Pandas and need your help. I have a dataset containing countries and regions. I have sorted them based on regions but i want to be able to access them by region only. i used

```
ds2[ds2.Region=='Africa']
```

but it's not returning anything rather it's giving me the column details. please can anyone be of help? thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible example? The code you provided doesn't seem problematic

Comment: is  it what you want`ds2['Region'][ds2.Region=='Africa']` ?

Comment: No, the problem is that I ran your code on another DataFrame with out a problem. So the problem is most likely elsewhere. To see what the problem is, I would need to see a reduced version of the DataFrame you're working with.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I have a dataset containing countries and region as column and I have been able to sort the countries based on their region. However, i want to be able to output a new dataset with only a particular country/region from the original dataset; for instance 'africa'. Hope his is clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your region column probably has white space and different cases.

this should work :

```
ds2.loc[ds2['Region'].str.strip().str.lower() == 'Africa']
```

note you could also do

```
ds2.loc[ds2['Region'].str.contains('Africa',case=False,regex=False)==True]
```

Comment: ds2.loc[ds2['Region'].str.contains('Africa',case=False,regex=False)==True] worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please can you explain what was the problem and why my previous code wasn't working? Thank you once again.

Comment: exactly what I said above, either `Africa` isnt the name of the region and it has additional characters, or there is white space, or there is different casing i.e `AfRica` does not equal `Africa` or `africa` or `'  Africa   '` hard to see without seing a reproducable dataset, just as your doctor will tell you pain is a sympton but not the underlyin cause, the doctor will need to see you to make a proper diagnosis and on the same vein a reproduicable dataset is needed to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Acctully this line of code totally right but try pandas query method in you case it's going to be `ds2.query('Region==Africa')` . Make sure that your condition parameter `('Africa')` exactly the same in dataset it's case sensitive or may Africa doesn't in dataset. Any way it's recommend to use query method it's more flexible specially in case having multiple conditions. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html